# How to remove/convert naive time to time zone aware in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to read a date of format DD-MM-YYYY format from HTML and Compare it with the datetime field named as widget_created_at in my model.

```
if data["field"] == "widget_created_at":
    date = datetime.strptime(data["data"], "%d-%m-%Y").date()
    if data["option"] == "before":
        filter_query = Q(widget_created_at__lt=date)
```

Then whenever this query is used for filtering in the below code

```
blogs = blogs.filter(filter_query)
```

RunTime warning for naive datetime appears. I tried every solution i found from here and google but the Error is still there. Please tell me how to avoid it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` you are creating for your filter has no timezone.

Have you looked at [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to "[localize](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic)" the filter date?  This would allow you to add a timezone to the filter date?